# How to add hyperlink with a title in ios app using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to add a website link inside UIAlertController to add it with my string message which means I don't use a textfield
and I need to add this hyperlink with a title tag to describe this link in swift.

so it's going to looks like a clickable button.

what I did so far which isn't working

```
var mysite = <a href=LINK URL\">TEXT</a>
let messageTxt = "hello people thanks for installing my apps \(my site)"
```

example

> [Vist About page here](https://stackoverflow.com/company/about)

Comment: Apart from this question, try to use UIAlertController instead of UIAlertView, which is already declared as deprecated.

Comment: you're right I'm just a beginner there's a lot of name there ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a attributed string within a textfield and add it within the UIAlertView.

Step 1: Create a extension of attributed string to find the link and add appropriate style for the link text.

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    public func SetAsLink(textToFind:String, linkURL:String) {

        let foundRange = self.mutableString.range(of: textToFind)
        if foundRange.location != NSNotFound {
            self.addAttribute(.link, value: linkURL, range: foundRange)
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2: Create a attributed string and add the style to it.

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Please Open this LINK!")
        attributedString.SetAsLink(textToFind: "LINK", linkURL: "http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Step 3: Create the alert view

```
let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Title", message: "message",
                                                    delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles: "Cancel")
```

Step 4: Create a un-editable text field

```
 let Txt:UITextView = UITextView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
```

Step 5 : Set attributed string to the text field

Txt.attributedText = attributedString;

Step 6: Make the txt field un-editable and detect link type

```
Txt.isEditable=false;
Txt.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.link;
```

Step 7: Set the text field to the alert and show the alert

```
     Txt.isEditable=false;
     Txt.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.link;
```

To summarise it

To show the alert :

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Please Open this LINK!")
        attributedString.SetAsLink(textToFind: "LINK", linkURL: "http://stackoverflow.com")

       let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Title", message: "message",
                                                    delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles: "Cancel")

        let Txt:UITextView = UITextView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        Txt.attributedText = attributedString;
        Txt.isEditable=false;
        Txt.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.link;

        alert.setValue(Txt, forKey: "accessoryView")
        alert.show()
```

Extending the attributed string

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    public func SetAsLink(textToFind:String, linkURL:String) {

        let foundRange = self.mutableString.range(of: textToFind)
        if foundRange.location != NSNotFound {
            self.addAttribute(.link, value: linkURL, range: foundRange)
        }
    }
}
```

P.S : Don't  forget to make your view controller the UIAlertViewDelegate.

Here is the [sample](https://github.com/pooja-kamath/AlertWithLink.git) project

If you are using CDAlertView you can try this:

```
let alert = CDAlertView(title: "Awesome Title", message: "Are you in?!", type: .notification)
let doneAction = CDAlertViewAction(title: "Sure! ")
alert.add(action: doneAction)
let nevermindAction = CDAlertViewAction(title: "Nevermind ")
alert.add(action: nevermindAction) 


let myCustomView = UIVIew(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,280,200))
  let Txt:UITextView = UITextView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
Txt.attributedText = attributedString;
Txt.isEditable=false;
Txt.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.link;
myCustomView.addSubview(Txt)          
alert.customView = myCustomView
alert.show()
```

Comment: the effort you did is really amazing I didn't find the xcode file in your sample project to see how it looks. I followed your steps but the app crashes there's a problem with alert.set value and can't add delegate: self to it. I'm not using the default alert it's a framework library.. don't know why apple making this complicated in HTML is one line

Comment: Nice it's working like a charm!! can you do the same with  [CDAlertView Library](https://github.com/candostdagdeviren/CDAlertView) cause it failed and where did you get this from forKey: "accessoryView"

Comment: Hello, thre's an issue with this line:  let myCustomView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,280,200)) .. "'CGRectMake' is unavailable in Swift" I tried to fix with "UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 280, height: 200))" but no text's appeared in this case

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to define the URL as a URL data type, and use the UIApplication:openURL method to open it in Safari.

In Swift this might be something like (code off the top of my head, not from an app):

```
let url = URL(string:"http://www.foobar.com")
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

This would startup Safari on the phone and open the URL inside Safari. If you wanted to do this in your app you'd need to start up a web view and open the URL in that view. Since you're building your URL from components, you'll need to use some other methods of URL rather than my simple example above.

But if you want to just thank your users, why use a web link? It's easier to just use a UILabel and set the text property of that to what you want to tell the user. That would be simpler than the web URL thing and more iOS-like. The initial value of that UILabel would be empty or just spaces.

Comment: I've a longer message it's just example I want to show them my privacy policy page

Comment: As I mentioned it's an example off the top of my head, not a working code snippet.